# During initramfs, udev ignores my mdadm raid 1, but raid is perfectly assembled within rescue

Tags: linux, boot, arch-linux, mdadm, udev

I know, yet another question about mdadm...

I'll try and be as clear as can be:

System:

```
Archlinux
Kernel 5.15.81-1-lts
systemd 252.2-3-arch
```

rescue:

```
ArchISO (with zfs module)
Kernel 5.10.78-1-lts
systemd 249.6-3-arch
Zfs 2.1.1-1
```

My system consists of two drives:

```
nvme{0,1}n1:
- p1 - F32 - md1 (Metadata=1.0, homehost=any)
- p2 - zfs - root fs
- p3 - luks - md3 (Metadata 1.0, homehost=any)
```

The Idea is as follows:

1. EFI detect either of the two first partition (Metadata 1.0 implies that raid data are at the end of the partition)
2. EFI start, calling initramfs
3. Udev rules **should** (*did*) assemble the different raid
4. Luks decipher the md3 and mount it.
5. Zfs-mount.service loads keys and mount fs
6. System is happily up and running

In rescue, I can assemble the raid, decipher and access everything.

I went and extracted initramfs, to check all udev rules.

I could assemble the raid using udev's rules's command line (`mdadm --incremental --export $devnode`)

I am not sur why he would ignore the devices (or even if it actually ignored them).

Though, all of it was working a day ago, at most...

FYI: the raids where both created like this:

$name and $part are respectively boot/1 and secure/3:

```bash
mdadm --create --metadata=1.0 --name=$name --raid-device=2 --homehost=any /dev/md$part /dev/nvme{0,1}n1p$part
```

I also tried creating a manual hook that simply assembled both raids it was checking for mdadm.conf and didn't seem to work (written from memory, I'll edit it asap, **edited**):

```bash
run_hook(){
    if [ -r /etc/mdadm.conf ] && [ -x /usr/bin/mdadm ]; then
        /usr/bin/mdadm -A /dev/md1 -c /etc/mdadm.conf
        /usr/bin/mdadm -A /dev/md3 -c /etc/mdadm.conf
    fi
}
```

I'll work on it later on (3:00 am...) and correct / complete as much info.

If you have any idea of where should i look for anything wrong ?

I'll provide as much info i can , but i only have my phone...

Thanks in advance